# Material ui datagrid I want to change my table data upon button click

Tags: material-ui

so what I am trying to do is change a key value in my data that is being passed into datagrid component from material ui. I have a button that I am rendering. However on that button click I would like to change data. Is there a possible way I can get the index of my button click? Here is my code

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridApi, GridCellValue } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';



function StarWarsTable({data}) {
    const [starWarsData, setStarWarsData] = useState([]);
    const columns = [
        {
          field: "action",
          headerName: "Action",
          sortable: false,
          renderCell: (params) => {
            const onClick = (e) => {
              e.stopPropagation(); // don't select this row after clicking
      
              const api = params.api;
              const thisRow = {};
      
               api
                .getAllColumns()
                .filter((c) => c.field !== "__check__" && !!c)
                .forEach(
                  (c, i) => {
                      
                      (thisRow[c.field] = params.getValue(params.id, c.field))
                        alert(i)
                  }
                );
               
      
              return alert(JSON.stringify(thisRow, null, 4));
            };
      //I want to change data of the nth element upon this button click
            return <Button onClick={onClick}>Click</Button>;
          },
        },
        { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 130 },
        { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 130 },
        { field: "birthYear", headerName: "Birth Year", width: 130 },
        { field: "gender", headerName: "Gender", width: 130 },
        { field: "homeworld", headerName: "Home world", width: 130 },
        { field: "species", headerName: "Species", width: 130 },
        { field: "favorite", headerName: "Is Favorite", width: 130},
      ];
  return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: '10%', height: 400, width: "75%" }}>
      <DataGrid rows={data} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[10]} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarWarsTable;
```